# Error Date and Time in Event Viewer of window log (system) C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to fetch date and Time from Event Viewer having level  Error for my application but not getting way to fetch by C# please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure you have read the [ask] topics before asking a question to ensure it will be well received and we can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`EventLogEntry.TimeGenerated`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.timegenerated(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
{
    eventLog.Source = "Application";
    foreach (EventLogEntry entry in eventLog.Entries)
    {
        DateTime errorTime = entry.TimeGenerated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man its working.